# Attribute connection failure in CityEngine2014.0

Tags: arcgis, esri, city

I found a problem that I used the same name of attribute in CGA rule and shape,but I couldn't connect the attribute.While the shp source file is in the directory of data in same project

The CGA file is follow

```
/**
 * File:    rule.cga
 * Created: 2 Aug 2018 01:10:56 GMT
 * Author:  hp
 */

version "2014.0"

#@Group("floor") @Description("建筑物高度")

attr floor=1 #This attribute is used to generate 3D model and there is the same name of attribute in the shape file


@Group("Settings") @Order(1) @Description("设置显示比例")

attr Scale=1


@Group("Settings") @Rand(0,1) @Order(2) @Description("设置透明度")

attr Opacity=1


@Group("Settings")@Range("whiteToBlack","greenToRed","yellowToRed","redToBlue","orangeToBlue","brownToBlue") @Order(3) @Description("设置填充颜色")

attr ColorRamp= "yellowToRed"


@Group("Settings") @Order(4) @Description("设置颜色范围")

attr ColorRange=1000


Lot-->

   color(colorRamp(ColorRamp,floor/ColorRange))//赋不同的颜色

   set(material.opacity,Opacity)//设置透明度    

   extrude(world.y,floor*Scale/100)//设置拉伸高度
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFdIy.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id2MO.png)

Comment: I have solved this problem,It is because that the "floor" is string in shape,so I need to transfer it to float.